# Duplicate data within a start and end time interval when joining (merging) tables

Tags: r, date, join, duplicates, timestamp

I have two data frames that I have to join. But when joining the two data tables I want to duplicate each row of the `df2` within the start time and the end time. Rest of the rows of the new data frame should display as `NA`.

I tried with `left join` but it doesn't duplicate the rows within the start and end time.

```r
df <- dplyr::left_join(df1, df2, by = "Session_start")
```

The two data frames look like below.

```
head(df1)
#         Session_start Robot_ID
# 1 2022-07-07 00:05:19       R1
# 2 2022-07-07 00:05:20       R2
# 3 2022-07-07 00:05:21       R3
# 4 2022-07-07 00:05:22       R4
# 5 2022-07-07 00:05:23       R5
# 6 2022-07-07 00:05:24       R6

df2
#         Session_start         Session_End Animal_ID
# 1 2022-07-07 00:05:19 2022-07-07 00:05:21       ID1
# 2 2022-07-07 00:05:24 2022-07-07 00:05:26       ID2
# 3 2022-07-07 00:05:27 2022-07-07 00:05:31       ID3
# 4 2022-07-07 00:05:33 2022-07-07 00:05:34       ID4
```

Desired output will be:

| Session_start | Robot_ID | Session_End | Animal_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-07-07 00:05:19 | R1 | 2022-07-07 00:05:21 | ID1 |
| 2022-07-07 00:05:20 | R2 | 2022-07-07 00:05:21 | ID1 |
| 2022-07-07 00:05:21 | R3 | 2022-07-07 00:05:21 | ID1 |
| 2022-07-07 00:05:22 | R4 | NA | NA |
| 2022-07-07 00:05:23 | R5 | NA | NA |
| 2022-07-07 00:05:24 | R6 | 2022-07-07 00:05:26 | ID1 |
| 2022-07-07 00:05:25 | R7 | 2022-07-07 00:05:26 | ID2 |
| 2022-07-07 00:05:26 | R8 | 2022-07-07 00:05:26 | ID2 |
| 2022-07-07 00:05:27 | R9 | 2022-07-07 00:05:31 | ID3 |
| 2022-07-07 00:05:28 | R10 | 2022-07-07 00:05:31 | ID3 |
| 2022-07-07 00:05:29 | R11 | 2022-07-07 00:05:31 | ID3 |
| 2022-07-07 00:05:30 | R12 | 2022-07-07 00:05:31 | ID3 |
| 2022-07-07 00:05:31 | R13 | 2022-07-07 00:05:31 | ID3 |
| 2022-07-07 00:05:32 | R14 | NA | NA |
| 2022-07-07 00:05:33 | R15 | 2022-07-07 00:05:34 | ID4 |
| 2022-07-07 00:05:34 | R16 | 2022-07-07 00:05:34 | ID4 |

How I do this using R?

### Data

```
df1 <- data.frame(Session_start=c("2022-07-07 00:05:19", "2022-07-07 00:05:20", "2022-07-07 00:05:21", 
                                  "2022-07-07 00:05:22", "2022-07-07 00:05:23", "2022-07-07 00:05:24", 
                                  "2022-07-07 00:05:25", "2022-07-07 00:05:26", "2022-07-07 00:05:27", 
                                  "2022-07-07 00:05:28", "2022-07-07 00:05:29", "2022-07-07 00:05:30", 
                                  "2022-07-07 00:05:31", "2022-07-07 00:05:32", "2022-07-07 00:05:33", 
                                  "2022-07-07 00:05:34"), 
                  Robot_ID =c("R1", "R2", "R3", "R4", "R5", "R6", "R7", "R8", "R9", "R10", 
                              "R11", "R12", "R13", "R14", "R15", "R16"))

df2 <- data.frame(Session_start=c("2022-07-07 00:05:19", "2022-07-07 00:05:24", 
                                  "2022-07-07 00:05:27", "2022-07-07 00:05:33"), 
                  Session_End=c("2022-07-07 00:05:21", "2022-07-07 00:05:26", 
                                "2022-07-07 00:05:31", "2022-07-07 00:05:34"), 
                  Animal_ID =c("ID1", "ID2", "ID3", "ID4"))
```

Answer (score 1):

First, find the indices `w`, where session start of `df` lie in between the session intervals of `df2` using `outer()`. Next `cbind` them to the respective slices. Finally `merge` the remainder.

```
w <- outer(df1[, 1], as.data.frame(t(df2[1:2])), 
           Vectorize(\(x, y) x >= y[1] & x <= y[2])) |>
  apply(2, which)

Map(\(x, y) cbind(df1[x, ], df2[y, -1]), w, seq_len(nrow(df2))) |>
  do.call(what=rbind) |> merge(df1, all=TRUE)
#          Session_start Robot_ID         Session_End Animal_ID
# 1  2022-07-07 00:05:19       R1 2022-07-07 00:05:21       ID1
# 2  2022-07-07 00:05:20       R2 2022-07-07 00:05:21       ID1
# 3  2022-07-07 00:05:21       R3 2022-07-07 00:05:21       ID1
# 4  2022-07-07 00:05:22       R4                <NA>      <NA>
# 5  2022-07-07 00:05:23       R5                <NA>      <NA>
# 6  2022-07-07 00:05:24       R6 2022-07-07 00:05:26       ID2
# 7  2022-07-07 00:05:25       R7 2022-07-07 00:05:26       ID2
# 8  2022-07-07 00:05:26       R8 2022-07-07 00:05:26       ID2
# 9  2022-07-07 00:05:27       R9 2022-07-07 00:05:31       ID3
# 10 2022-07-07 00:05:28      R10 2022-07-07 00:05:31       ID3
# 11 2022-07-07 00:05:29      R11 2022-07-07 00:05:31       ID3
# 12 2022-07-07 00:05:30      R12 2022-07-07 00:05:31       ID3
# 13 2022-07-07 00:05:31      R13 2022-07-07 00:05:31       ID3
# 14 2022-07-07 00:05:32      R14                <NA>      <NA>
# 15 2022-07-07 00:05:33      R15 2022-07-07 00:05:34       ID4
# 16 2022-07-07 00:05:34      R16 2022-07-07 00:05:34       ID4
```

**Note:** Even though, the solution works without it (the dates are compared alphabetically), you should always use `"POSIXct"` format when you work with date-times. If you don't have it yet, convert it:

```
df1$Session_start <- as.POSIXct(df1$Session_start)
df2[1:2] <- lapply(df2[1:2], as.POSIXct)
```

Answer (score 1):

*data.table* with a non-equi, update-join might make this considerably nicer:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)
setDT(df2)
df1[
    df2,
    on=.(Session_start>=Session_start, Session_start<=Session_End),
    c("Animal_ID","Session_End") := .(i.Animal_ID, i.Session_End)
]
df1
##          Session_start Robot_ID Animal_ID         Session_End
## 1: 2022-07-07 08:05:19       R1       ID1 2022-07-07 08:05:21
## 2: 2022-07-07 08:05:20       R2       ID1 2022-07-07 08:05:21
## 3: 2022-07-07 08:05:21       R3       ID1 2022-07-07 08:05:21
## 4: 2022-07-07 08:05:22       R4      <NA>                <NA>
## 5: 2022-07-07 08:05:23       R5      <NA>                <NA>
## 6: 2022-07-07 08:05:24       R6       ID2 2022-07-07 08:05:26
## 7: 2022-07-07 08:05:25       R7       ID2 2022-07-07 08:05:26
## 8: 2022-07-07 08:05:26       R8       ID2 2022-07-07 08:05:26
## 9: 2022-07-07 08:05:27       R9       ID3 2022-07-07 08:05:31
##10: 2022-07-07 08:05:28      R10       ID3 2022-07-07 08:05:31
##11: 2022-07-07 08:05:29      R11       ID3 2022-07-07 08:05:31
##12: 2022-07-07 08:05:30      R12       ID3 2022-07-07 08:05:31
##13: 2022-07-07 08:05:31      R13       ID3 2022-07-07 08:05:31
##14: 2022-07-07 08:05:32      R14      <NA>                <NA>
##15: 2022-07-07 08:05:33      R15       ID4 2022-07-07 08:05:34
##16: 2022-07-07 08:05:34      R16       ID4 2022-07-07 08:05:34
```

Comment: I get a error here. Error in bmerge(i, x, leftcols, rightcols, roll, rollends, nomatch, mult,  : 
  Only '==' operator is supported for columns of type character.

Comment: The timestamps need to be converted to actual datetime objects instead of characters. See jay.sf's comment below.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is much longer than thelatemail's and jay.sf's, but I'll still post it, so you have more ideas.

My approach was to use auxiliary variables, use lubridate to be sure I was working with the right format, and then start propagating Animal_ID and Session_End data.

```r
# Loading libraries -------------------------------------------------------

library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

# Defining datasets -------------------------------------------------------

Session_start <-
  c(
    "2022-07-07 00:05:19",
    "2022-07-07 00:05:24",
    "2022-07-07 00:05:27",
    "2022-07-07 00:05:33"
  )

Session_End <-
  c(
    "2022-07-07 00:05:21",
    "2022-07-07 00:05:26",
    "2022-07-07 00:05:31",
    "2022-07-07 00:05:34"
  )

Animal_ID <- c("ID1", "ID2", "ID3", "ID4")

df2 <- data.frame(Session_start, Session_End, Animal_ID)

Session_start <-
  c(
    "2022-07-07 00:05:19",
    "2022-07-07 00:05:20",
    "2022-07-07 00:05:21",
    "2022-07-07 00:05:22",
    "2022-07-07 00:05:23",
    "2022-07-07 00:05:24",
    "2022-07-07 00:05:25",
    "2022-07-07 00:05:26",
    "2022-07-07 00:05:27",
    "2022-07-07 00:05:28",
    "2022-07-07 00:05:29",
    "2022-07-07 00:05:30",
    "2022-07-07 00:05:31",
    "2022-07-07 00:05:32",
    "2022-07-07 00:05:33",
    "2022-07-07 00:05:34"
  )

Robot_ID <-
  c(
    "R1",
    "R2",
    "R3",
    "R4",
    "R5",
    "R6",
    "R7",
    "R8",
    "R9",
    "R10",
    "R11",
    "R12",
    "R13",
    "R14",
    "R15",
    "R16"
  )

df1 <- data.frame(Session_start, Robot_ID)

# Joining with data propagation -------------------------------------------

df <-
  dplyr::left_join(df1, df2, by = "Session_start") |>
  arrange(Session_start) |>
  mutate(
    Session_start =
      Session_start |>
      lubridate::as_datetime(),
    Session_End =
      Session_End |>
      lubridate::as_datetime()
  ) |>
  mutate(
    is_na_Session_End = if_else(
      condition = is.na(Session_End),
      true = FALSE,
      false = TRUE
    ),
    number_of_non_NA_Session_End = cumsum(is_na_Session_End)
  ) |>
  group_by(number_of_non_NA_Session_End) |>
  mutate(Session_End =
           Session_End |>
           first(),
         Animal_ID =
           Animal_ID |>
           first()) |>
  mutate(
    Session_End = if_else(
      condition = Session_start <= Session_End,
      true = Session_End,
      false = NA_POSIXct_
    ),
    Animal_ID = if_else(
      condition = Session_start <= Session_End,
      true = Animal_ID,
      false = NA_character_
    )
  ) |>
  ungroup() |>
  select(-is_na_Session_End,
         -number_of_non_NA_Session_End) |>
  as.data.frame()

df
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my answer. It's a little simple, but it works fine with your dataset:

```
# Package needed
library(dplyr)

# First, preprocess the data
df1 <- df1 %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(Session_start), as.POSIXct)

df2 <- df2 %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(Session_start, Session_End), as.POSIXct)

df3 <- merge(df1, df2, all = TRUE)

# Then, fill the voids 
for (i in 1:nrow(df3)) {
  
  if (!is.na(df3$Session_End[i])) {
    
    session_end1 <- df3$Session_End[i]
    animal_id1 <- df3$Animal_ID[i]
    
  } else {
    
    if (i < nrow(df3)) {
      
      if (df3$Session_start[i] < df3$Session_start[i+1]) {
        
        df3$Session_End[i] <- session_end1
        df3$Animal_ID[i] <- animal_id1
        
      }
      
    } else if (i == nrow(df3)) {
      
      df3$Session_End[i] <- session_end1
      df3$Animal_ID[i] <- animal_id1
      
    }
    
  }
  
}
```